# Sklearn PCA explained variance and explained variance ratio difference

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, covariance

I'm trying to get the variances from the eigen vectors.

What is the difference between `explained_variance_ratio_` and `explained_variance_` in `PCA`?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **percentage** of the explained variance is:

```
explained_variance_ratio_
```

The **variance** i.e. the eigenvalues of the covariance matrix is:

```
explained_variance_
```

Formula:
`explained_variance_ratio_ = explained_variance_ / np.sum(explained_variance_)`

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(X)
```

```
pca.explained_variance_
array([7.93954312, 0.06045688]) # the actual eigenvalues (variance)

pca.explained_variance_ratio_ # the percentage of the variance
array([0.99244289, 0.00755711])
```

Also based on the above formula:

`7.93954312 / (7.93954312+ 0.06045688) = 0.99244289`

From the documentation:

> explained_variance_ : array, shape (n_components,) The amount of
>   variance explained by each of the selected components.
>
> Equal to n_components largest eigenvalues of the covariance matrix of
>   X.
>
> New in version 0.18.
>
> explained_variance_ratio_ : array, shape (n_components,) Percentage of
>   variance explained by each of the selected components.
>
> If n_components is not set then all components are stored and the sum
>   of the ratios is equal to 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

The example used by @seralouk unfortunately already has only 2 components. So, the explanation for `pca.explained_variance_ratio_` is incomplete.

The denominator should be the sum of `pca.explained_variance_ratio_` for the original set of features before PCA was applied, where the number of components can be greater than the number of components used in PCA.

Here is an explanation of this quantity using the iris dataset.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

iris=datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data     
#y = iris.target   

pca_2c_model=PCA(n_components=2)
x_pca_2c=pca_2c_model.fit_transform(X) 

print('Explained variance:\n', pca_2c_model.explained_variance_)

print('Explained variance ratio:\n', pca_2c_model.explained_variance_ratio_)
```

returns

```
Explained variance: 
 [4.22824171 0.24267075]
Explained variance ratio:
 [0.92461872 0.05306648]
```

The quantity `pca_2c_model.explained_variance_` contains the diagonal elements of the covariance of the two principal components. For principal components, by very definition the covariance matrix should be diagonal.

```
var=np.cov(x_pca_2c.T)
explained_var=var.diagonal()
print('Explained variance calculated manually is\n',explained_var)
```

returns

```
Explained variance calculated manually is
 [4.22824171 0.24267075]
```

To calculate the ratio, the denominator has to be calculated for the original set of features before PCA (i.e. on all components). So, we can just use the trace of the covariance of the full set of features to find the ratio. Here, we are using the idea of trace invariance of a matrix.

```
all_var=np.cov(X.T)
sum_all_var=np.sum(all_var.diagonal()) # same as np.trace(all_var)
explained_var_ratio=explained_var/sum_all_var
print('Explained variance ratio calculated manually is\n',explained_var_ratio)
```

returns

```
Explained variance ratio calculated manually is
 [0.92461872 0.05306648]
```

Further,

```
print(sum(explained_var_ratio))
```

returns

```
0.9776852063187955
```

So, the sum of `explained_variance_ratio_` does not add to 1.0 implying that the small deviation from 1.0 is contained in the other components of the original feature space.

Comment: Can you explain why variance is preserved?

Answer (score 2):

It's just normalization to see how each principal component important. You can say:
`explained_variance_ratio_ = explained_variance_/np.sum(explained_variance_)`